# Exiting loop in Arduino after doing an operation for specific number of times

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-esp8266

I want to turn on light/solenoid valve on and off 30 times only, and after that I want to exit the loop. How can I modify the void loop in Arduino? My program is given below.

```
int relay = 8;
void setup() {
    // Put your setup code here, to run once:
    pinMode(relay, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    // Put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    digitalWrite(relay, HIGH);
    delay(5000);
    digitalWrite(relay, LOW);
    delay(200);
}
```

Comment: In most microcontrollers using C/C++, you **never** exit the loop.  You can turn a block of code on of off, `if (count == 20) continue;` or otherwise control it, skip it, whatever.  Some micros have a `halt` ASM instruction or similar, but many do not.  As always, read the datasheet and the manufacturer's suggestions for coding idioms in the languages for which they offer examples.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to move your code out of the `loop` function (which is called forever in a loop), and instead to call your code once in the `setup` function (which is called once).

You then can wrap your code in a `for loop` to have it repeat n times (in this case 30).

Here is an example (which obviously can be refactored), but should demonstrate what you are trying to accomplish:

```c
int relay = 8;

void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    pinMode(relay, OUTPUT);

    // toggle 30 times
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        digitalWrite(relay, HIGH);
        delay(5000);
        digitalWrite(relay, LOW);
        delay(200);
    }
}

void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot for clarifying me not to use the void loop. Your modification to the program is working great with my experimental setup. Thanks again for your help.